# how to find the difference in dates stored in 2 columns of mysql of same row

Tags: java, mysql, database, date, datediff

```
    dtchkt=obj.next();
    String ddf;
    rs=st.executeQuery("select datediff(dtchkt,dtchki) where id="+id);
    while(rs.next())
    {   
        ddf=rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println(ddf);        
    }
```

the above code is not working for finding difference between dates of two columns actually i want the code to return the no of days between the two specified dates of column.Please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: change `datediff('dtchkt','dtchki')` to `datediff(dtchkt,dtchki)`. as these are the names of your fields, they are not string literals

Comment: thanks but still it is giving me a syntax error at 3 line of above code

Comment: your missing the from clause ( what table are you reading from ). add that, and post the exact contents of the query string ( when expanded ) and the table ddl

Comment: yeah i  realised my mistake thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rs=st.executeQuery("select datediff(dtchkt,dtchki) FROM `table_name` where id="+id);
```